# What is wrong with my socks v5 handshake?

Tags: c++, c, network-programming, socks

I am trying to make my program direct it's traffic through tor by implementing SOCKS5 and so far I've got this:

```
char first =(0x00,0x01,0x05);
char sec=(0x50,0x00,0xE2,0xE1,0x7D,0x4A,0x01,0x00,0x01,0x05);
send(ProxySocket, &first,(int) 3,0);
send(ProxySocket, &sec, (int) sizeof(sec),0);
```

But when I run my program tor tells me "[warn] fetching socks handshake failed. closing."
is there something wrong with the packets that i am sending?

Comment: When did the compiler think this would compile?

Comment: @Ed Heal: code will definitely compile.

Comment: @dbasic - I wish to withdraw my statement but I think that the code is what userX is not expecting due to thinking that it will be a list.

Comment: @Ed Heal: You are right. Code is definitely not expected by the User.

Comment: @Ed Heal: I am unable to understand this. You are right in saying that this is not the expected code and declarations would not result in array/list.

Comment: @Dbasic - The better half always thinks that I am wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is wrong.
Value of
     char first = (0x00, 0x01, 0x05);
will be 0x05. See the rule of parenthesis in the assignment.
I think it should be 
     char first[] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x05};
Now you can use sizeof operator in first.

In the second send call, you are using sizeof(sec) which turns out one char.

Use:

```
 char sec[] = {0x50,0x00,0xE2,0xE1,0x7D,0x4A,0x01,0x00,0x01,0x05};
```

Your code should be:

```
char first[] ={0x00,0x01,0x05};
char sec[]={0x50,0x00,0xE2,0xE1,0x7D,0x4A,0x01,0x00,0x01,0x05};
send(ProxySocket, first,(int) sizeof(first),0);
send(ProxySocket, sec, (int) sizeof(sec),0);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, that did the trick.! As you might have noticed I'm just getting used to C and C++.